# What is preventing the click event at the end of this JS script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just can't see the error that is preventing the Intro tab from being set as the active tab on load thanks to the 'defaultOpen' id. It doesn't change color until it is clicked, it should look that way without having to click it. This is a simple copy of the [W3Schools HowTo lesson on Tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp), but something isn't right.

```js
function openContent(evt, contentType) {
  var i, tabcontent, tabheads;
  tabcontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  tabheads =
    document.getElementsByClassName('tabheads');
  for (i = 0; i < tabheads.length; i++) {
    tabheads[i].className =
      tabheads[i].className.replace(' active', '')
  }
  document.getElementById(contentType).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}

document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();
```

```css
.outerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.7);
}
.innerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.7);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 25px;
}
.innerDiv p {
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center;
}
ul.tabs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1rem 0 0.3rem 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.tabs li a {
  padding: 0 1.2rem 0.5rem 1.2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #96912d;
  margin: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0.3rem;
}
.tabs li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}
.tabs li a:focus,
.tabs li a .active {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.7);
  color: #fac819;
}
.under-tabs {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads" onclick="openContent(event,'intro')" id="defaultOpen">Intro</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads" onclick="openContent(event,'blog')">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabheads" onclick="openContent(event,'comments')">Comments</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="innerDiv under-tabs tabcontent" id="intro">
      <p>
        This project is building a series of virtual colonies on the Moon.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabcontent" id="blog">
      <iframe src="blogMain.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="tabcontent" id="comments">
      Comment section!!!
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an error in the style

```
.tabs li a:focus, .tabs li a.active {
   background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.7);
   color: #fac819; 
}
```

In the css, you have space between `a` tag and `.active` class because the class is attached attached to the a element

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I see now - a class name on an element, not just a class name within a parent element. So, no space. I stared at this for a really long time before i finally asked... I'm not very good at catching the details.

Comment: Helping and being helped by others always let you learn new things. So thank you for that. Have a good coding time. :-)